# powerpoint365 automatisation in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, powerpoint

The program has worked under Win10 and Microsoft Office well.
Now I have changed to WIN 11 and Office365 and nothing works.

In spite of
*Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint*"
VB answers
*he type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application' is not defined*".
The same happens with .presentation  + .slide and .slideshowsetting .

Here is  my code

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel


Public Class frmPowerpoint_Präsentation


    Public Shared PowerPointType As Type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("PowerPoint.Application")
    Public Shared PowerPoint As Object = Activator.CreateInstance(PowerPointType)
    Public Shared objppApplication As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application
    Public Shared objppPresentation As Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Presentation
    Private Shared objSlide As Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Slide
   
    Private objSettings As Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.SlideShowSettings
```

How can I solve this

UPS

I have tried to change  to change to

```
'// PowerPoint automation
Dim PowerPointType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID(\"PowerPoint.Application\")
Dim PowerPoint = Activator.CreateInstance(PowerPointType)
Dim oApp As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Application
Dim oPres As Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim oSlide As PowerPoint.Slide

'// Open MS PowerPoint in a hidden window
oPres = oApp.Presentations.Open(ppt_filename,,,Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse)
```

but it did'nt work as well.

Comment: When you say nothing works? We need a bit more explain. Keep in mind that with vs2022 you need to force the project to x32 bits (if using Office x32). And if you using office x64 bits, then again, you need/want to force your project to x64 bits.